# fill color for rectangle stays black though when I set it to red

Tags: python, tkinter

(excerpt from my program's code)

```
global pensize
global rect1
try:
    pensize
except:
    pensize = 0
global pencolor
try:
    pencolor
except:
    pencolor = "red"
def callback(event):
    global rect1
    rect1 = canvas.create_rectangle(event.x-pensize, event.y-pensize, event.x+pensize, event.y+pensize, fill="red")
    print(pencolor)
def setpencolor(color):
    global pencolor
    pencolor = color
    global rect1
    canvas.itemconfig(rect1, fill=pencolor)
    print("Pencolor set to"+str(pencolor))

#    --- window properties ---
# --- the canvas ---
canvas= Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", callback)
canvas.pack(side = RIGHT)
# --- the menubar ---
menubar = Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
#   --- color tool---
colormenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
colormenu.add_command(label="Black", command=lambda: setpencolor("black"))
colormenu.add_command(label="Red", command=lambda: setpencolor("red"))
colormenu.add_command(label="Blue", command=lambda: setpencolor("blue"))
menubar.add_cascade(label="Color", menu=colormenu)
```

This is part of a drawing program I'm making. I'd like to make it so that when the user changes color, it changes not only the color of the pen but also everything else they've drawn. None of those concepts work, though. The fill color for the rectangle stays black, even though pencolor is clearly set to "red". While it's supposed to change the color of everything else, it does absolutely nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `fill=pencolor` in `create_rectangle(...)` inside `callback()`.

Comment: My first answer was wrong.  I tried your example, modified a bit, and found your issue.  It has to do with the outline of each rectangle.  If you had made larger rectangles, you would have seen that the fill was the right color, it is the outline that was black.

Comment: I fixed my answer once again, based on your clarifying remarks.  To change existing widgets, you must find all of the elements on the canvas using `canvas.findall()` then change each of them by the id using `canvas.itemconfigure()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

After playing with your example, I believe that this is related to your pen size.  You are only seeing the border, which is always black.  I have cut your example down a bit and the below works almost as expected.  Notice the black border around each rectangle?  That is what you are looking to change.

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()

# --- the canvas ---
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
canvas.grid()

global pensize, pencolor
pensize = 3
pencolor = 'red'

def callback(event):
    canvas.create_rectangle(
        event.x-pensize, event.y-pensize, 
        event.x+pensize, event.y+pensize, 
        fill=pencolor, outline=pencolor)

def setpencolor(color, canvas):
    global pencolor
    pencolor = color

    elements = canvas.find_all()

    for element in elements:
        canvas.itemconfigure(element, fill=color, outline=color)

canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", callback)

# --- color tool---
tk.Button(root, text='black', 
    command=lambda: setpencolor("black", canvas)).grid()
tk.Button(root, text='red', 
    command=lambda: setpencolor("red", canvas)).grid()
tk.Button(root, text='blue', 
    command=lambda: setpencolor("blue", canvas)).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Now, try to create the rectangle as follows:

```
canvas.create_rectangle(
    event.x-pensize, event.y-pensize, 
    event.x+pensize, event.y+pensize, 
    fill=pencolor, outline=pencolor
)
```

To answer the last part of your question, you must now find all elements on the canvas and use `itemconfigure` to change their properties:

```
elements = canvas.find_all()

for element in elements:
    canvas.itemconfigure(element, fill=color, outline=color)
```